# ios error "plugin com.swiftkey.SwiftKeyApp.Keyboard invalidated"

Tags: ios, swift

I have a simple app which logs in with username / password then redirect it to webview.When i am on webview and come back to app login form where users key in to login again,it throws me the error

```
"plugin com.swiftkey.SwiftKeyApp.Keyboard invalidated",
```

although it happens only when i connect and test on deivce,it is perfectly fine on simulator

i tried it on ios8.1 - iphone 4s.

virtually no help available anywhere.

---

just found out it is happening due to swift key app which is installed for dictionary prediction. But still no clue how to make it work with that.